# Typescript transpile errors appear only on production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, pm2

Somewhere along the lines of updating my node version / dependencies for both machines, I noticed
that building my app in production on another machine outputs an error while building for production on my main machine does not.

The errors go away if I move the affected devDependencies to the dependencies array in my `package.json`, but that's more of a workaround and I would like to know why I'm seeing the different behavior.

As far as I understand, when running `npm install` in production, it will *not* install my dev dependencies.
This is fine since I tested this on my dev machine, and the app built fine even without my dev dependencies.

However, in production, I get errors such as these:

`Cannot find module 'sinon' or its corresponding type declarations.`

`` Could not find a declaration file for module 'cors'. '/home/ubuntu/brobot/source/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cors` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cors'; ``

They go away if I move the affected packages to the dependencies array instead of dev dependencies, but why? And why does it build fine without my dev dependencies on my dev machine?

Here are my configurations:

`package.json` shortened:

```
{
  "main": "dist/src/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev:old": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon -q -r dotenv/config --es-module-specifier-resolution=node dist/src/index.js\"",
    "deploy": "pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.cjs production",
    "preserve": "npm run build",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@pkmn/randoms": "^0.5.11",
    "@pkmn/sim": "^0.5.11",
    "@twurple/api": "^5.0.18",
    "@twurple/auth": "^5.0.18",
    "@twurple/chat": "^5.0.18",
    "@twurple/eventsub": "^5.0.18",
    "@twurple/eventsub-ngrok": "^5.0.18",
    "@types/cookie-session": "^2.0.44",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/express-ws": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.7",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.8",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-ws": "^5.0.2",
    "helmet": "^5.0.2",
    "mocha": "^9.2.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.8",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "winston": "^3.6.0",
    "ws": "^8.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/sinon": "^10.0.11",
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.16.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "pm2": "^5.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "sinon": "^13.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts}": [
      "eslint --cache --fix",
      "prettier --check"
    ]
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "ESNext",                             /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */     /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,                              /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "dist",                               /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",                     /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

`PM2 ecosystem.config.cjs:`

```
require('dotenv').config();

// Default configuration
module.exports = {
    apps: [...],
    deploy: {
        production: {
            user: process.env.AWS_USER,
            host: process.env.AWS_PUBLIC_IP,
            key: process.env.AWS_SSH_KEY,
            ref: 'origin/main',
            repo: '...',
            path: process.env.AWS_EC2_PATH,
            node_args: "--experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node",
            env: { NODE_ENV: 'production', },
            'post-deploy':
                'npm install && npm run build && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.cjs --env production'
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is where errors are thrown in production. `npm run build` works fine on development without dev dependencies installed.
        }
    }
};
```

**Things I've considered:**

- Don't transpile in production. I am cloning my repo during the deploy process so I can't do this unless I include my build in my repo.
- Switch devDependencies to dependencies: I really want to avoid doing this since they *should* be dev dependencies

**Other things I've tried:**

- Clearing npm cache
- Deleting my PM2 instance completely and reconfiguring it
- Deleting package-lock.json (I know this is bad but I'm desperate, no conflicts seen)
- Removing --experimental-modules and adding back ".js" extension imports
- Excluding my node_modules in tsconfig.json

There's gotta be some misconfiguration between my dev/prod machines. Although they are running the same version of node and Typescript.
Both machines are not using globally installed packages as far as I'm aware. The weird thing is that this worked on my production machine just fine before, although I may have not been running it with the production flag correctly. Even though my node_env was "production", it might have been installing my dev dependencies without me noticing.

I'm running out of options here and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sinon is a dev dependency so it's not bundled for production. If you need it for production you can add it to a dependency, if not you can remove the reference to sinon and rebundle and it should resolve itself.

Edit 1:

> The errors go away if I move the affected devDependencies to the dependencies array in my package.json

I initially glossed over this. Yeah, it sounds like you are using these libraries in your production code but since they aren't in dependencies they aren't included in your production bundle. They work in development because you have them as dev dependencies.

Comment: But why do I need it for production? It's only used for testing and doesn't affect the app when I build _without_ my dev dependencies on my local machine. If I delete my node_modules,  `npm install --production`, and then `npm run build` on my local machine, it works fine without the sinon package. But in production, doing the same results in those errors

Comment: Your code dictates what you "need" for production. If you are using a library in your code and it's a dev dependency it'll work on dev but not necessarily be included in your production bundle. Are you hosting it the same? I know that my local environment is set up to use dev environment and corresponding variables. Confirm your environment and variables are the same but it still sounds like it's the case of dev dependencies not being included in the production build but used in the production code.

Comment: As far as I understand, my code runs fine in production without moving them to devDependencies. If I clone my repo on my local machine, and ONLY install my dependencies (not dev dependencies), then `npm run build` (specifically tsc) works fine. The same can't be said on my production server for whatever reason. Even though the production server does the exact same, it clones my repo and builds.

Comment: Again, confirm your environmental variables as they will ultimately determine what's installed. But from everything you're saying it sounds like your production code relies on those libraries and you've included them as dev dependencies so they wouldn't be bundled with a production build.

Comment: I see the issue now. It seems I misinterpreted the `npm install --production` on my local machine. Even though I deleted my node_modules, and installed with the production flag, I thought it would not use my dev dependencies no matter what my NODE_ENV was set to. Switching my NODE_ENV to production replicates this issue on my local machine. Thank you for the help! I'll mark your answer as correct since it led me down the right path.

Comment: Yeah, some of the commands can be unintuitive but always fallback to confirming assumptions and verify everything. I'm glad I could help! Best of luck going forward with your project! :D